# How to switch git protocol from https to ssh only when authentication needed

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using YubiKey (PIV smart card with USB) to store my ssh credential for GitHub.
Every time I access to GitHub via ssh, I need to insert the key and put pin.
It's a bit stressful and I want to avoid it if it is not needed.
For example, on cloning the public repo, I don't need to authenticate when I do that via https.

I can enforce git client to use ssh everywhere:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

But I do not want to enforce ssh everywhere. I want it only when authentication is needed.

Does anyone know good ways?

Comment: You can try `pushInsteadOf`. This overwrites it only for write access. But e.g. private repos will still not work.

Comment: I'm using `pushInsteadOf` currently. I have to put username and token (instead of password, as I'm using 2FA) for cloning private repo, which is quite annoying.

Comment: As the answer from @demas states, you can set the remote for private repositories and use `pushInsteadOf` for public repos.

Comment: You could also write a custom script that tries to do that using http and tries it again using SSH (if it prompts for authentication). Maybe an init script that sets the remote depending on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change remote url to `http` protocol using: `git remote set-url origin http://new.git.url/here`.

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

Comment: Yes, you can do that per repo. I don't want to do that every time I clone a new repo.

Comment: You can clone it using http protocol: `git clone http://....`.

Comment: I'm using [ghq](https://github.com/x-motemen/ghq). I cannot choose the protocol on cloning when executing `ghq get aiotter/dotfiles` for example.

Comment: I didn't use `ghq`, but in the repository description I have found example with http: `$ ghq get https://github.com/x-motemen/ghq
# Runs git clone https://github.com/x-motemen/ghq ~/ghq/github.com/x-motemen/ghq`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I'm asking about is automatic way of switching protocol on git client. I don't want to resolve the problem per-repo basis.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't provide a way to do this natively, and if you want to use HTTPS for public repositories and SSH for private repositories, you'll need to do that by hand.

The reason for this is that Git doesn't intrinsically know that two different repository URLs map to the same repository.  While there are common patterns, what works for GitHub doesn't work for my personal server, so it can't assume anything about the operation.  You therefore have to be explicit about what you want.

Also, the only way Git would be able to know that a remote HTTPS server requires authentication would be to attempt to make a request.  So in order to accomplish what you want, it would have to make an HTTP request, realize it got a 401, abort the entire separate HTTP helper, roll back, internally change the protocol, and then spawn an entirely new process to do that.  Needless to say, Git doesn't have that support.

As others have suggested, you could use SSH URLs for your private repos and use HTTPS URLs for your public repos with a `pushInsteadOf` setting in your `~/.gitconfig`, but that would be the only way to accomplish what you want.